# how can i set all screen width in layout in android

Tags: android, layout

I make a menu without action bar, just with a layout with buttons vertical and background black but the problem is that the layout in width is not show in all screen

like this

http://sia1.subirimagenes.net/img/2014/01/11/140111103045646326.png

the xml of the layout is this

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/page1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:visibility="visible" >
```

Comment: Did you used prefixed width for your layout or wrap_content?

Comment: I was use fill parent

Answer (score 0):

Set the height to wrap_content!

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/page1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:visibility="visible" >
```

Comment: thanks for you answer it work remove of principal relative layout android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"